# How can I auto start Tor Browser Bundle in Debian?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, debian

I'd like to start Tor Browser automatically on statup. What is the best way to do it?

I'm using Debian 7 "Wheezy" with Gnome 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in terminal type `gnome-session-properties` then check the tor option in list
if tor is not in the list then you can add it

[image: startup applications preferences]

Comment: This only works for Gnome. On Debaian you may be using KDE, or XFCE, or many others.

Comment: you're right. I assumed he uses gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the correct session file

http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/cool_unix/xinitrc.html